# Factory pattern to access a static method

Tags: php, factory

I am new to the factory pattern and have the following factory method:

```
public static function build($class) {
  $class = Helper::str_lreplace("_", "_" . System_Config::getConfig("ef_platform"), $class);
  return new $class;
}
```

How do I use the same factory pattern, but for a static method? For example, I have the following method calls:

```
   Order_WooExport::registerActions();
   Order_WooExport::registerFilters();
```

but I want to call:

```
   Order_WPExport::registerActions();
   Order_WPExport::registerFilters();
```

depending on the value of `System_Config::getConfig("ef_platform");`

Comment: Static factories (and really static anythings) are an antipattern. Create an instantiable factory class instead which can be injected instead, as this provides loose coupling. If you want to typehint for something, use an interface.

Comment: [Example of the pattern described above](http://codepad.org/L1yqspQO).

Answer (score 0):

Provided `str_lreplace("_", "_" . System_Config::getConfig("ef_platform")` gives you theclass name you want to use and provided you're using PHP 5.3+, you could try [forward_static_call](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.forward-static-call.php) or something similar :

```
$class = str_lreplace("_", "_" . System_Config::getConfig("ef_platform");
forward_static_call(array($class, 'registerActions'));
forward_static_call(array($class, 'registerFilters'));
```